# Warning: Division by zero on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a WordPress plugin and what it does is actually fetch a JSON API via a URL and it shows price using Loop. And I want to show current WooCommerce product price is divided by the fetched price. But, it all time shows me a error: Warning: Division by Zero. I am writing the code here. Could anyone please tell me what did I have done wrong?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', function($price) {

$url = 'https://bitpay.com/api/rates';
$details = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($details, true);

$bitprice = $json[0][rate];
echo $bitprice / $price;    

});
```

Comment: do this `print $price`

Comment: have you checked $price before dividing ? could you tell what you have tried to debug code and find error ?

Comment: @FerozAkbar I want to show the price by divide it with $bitprice

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes, I have checked the price before dividing it and $price shows the price correctly but when I am trying to divide it with $bitprice then it shows, Warning: Dividing by Zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should be `$bitprice = $json[0]["rate"];` instead of `$bitprice = $json[0][rate];` , do not use implicit conversion by PHP, that is prone to error.
2. Your price value is a string, which is not getting converted to an integer properly, hence being typecasted as 0.

Comment: Can you please let me know then can I made $price to an Integer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$bitprice = intval($json[0][rate]);
echo $bitprice / $price;
```

`intval` is a WordPress built-in function that converts string to int.

**Edit**:

Try this

```
$bitprice = intval($json[0]["rate"]);
echo $bitprice / $price;
```

Comment: Hi, intval doesn't working. It's still showing the same error. It's still don't convert to Integer